# ERROR_PATCH_SAME_FILE same files

Tags: patch

Could you please help me to force creation of patches for 2 files that were built in different time from the same sources on build-server and have different md5 (the difference is byte 0000088).

CreatePatchFileExW(countOldFiles,oldFileInfoArray,targetFile,deltaFile,PatchOptionFlags(optimizePatchSizeForLargeFiles),pod,null,IntPtr.Zero)

returns error ERROR_PATCH_SAME_FILE.

Could you please help me how to force patch to be created when difference is just one byte?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is delete flag PATCH_OPTION_FAIL_IF_SAME_FILE